# Keep application running after leiningen main returns

Tags: clojure, javafx, leiningen

In my clojure application I have a JavaFX window and the application closes after the main function returns.  I'd like the application to stay open until the user closes the window (or selects "exit" from the menu, or something).

How do I do that?

Here's the core.clj file, the last 20 lines or so are the relevant ones:

```
(ns pdb-java-client.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:import (javafx.scene.control LabelBuilder)))



;; JavaFX UI

(import '(javafx.scene SceneBuilder)
        '(javafx.scene.canvas CanvasBuilder Canvas GraphicsContext)
        '(javafx.scene.control ButtonBuilder)
        '(javafx.scene.layout VBoxBuilder)
        '(javafx.scene.image WritableImage PixelWriter)
        '(javafx.scene.transform Scale Translate)
        '(javafx.stage StageBuilder))

; instead of extending javafx.application.Application
(defonce force-toolkit-init (javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.))

; some helper functions and macros to make JavaFX easier to type
(defn run-later*
  [f]
  (javafx.application.Platform/runLater f))

(defmacro run-later
  [& body]
  `(run-later* (fn [] ~@body)))

(defn run-now*
  [f]
  (let [result (promise)]
    (run-later
      (deliver result (try (f) (catch Throwable e e))))
    @result))

(defmacro run-now
  [& body]
  `(run-now* (fn [] ~@body)))

(defn event-handler*
  [f]
  (reify javafx.event.EventHandler
    (handle [this e] (f e))))

(defmacro event-handler [arg & body]
  `(event-handler* (fn ~arg ~@body)))

(def stage (atom nil))

; build a scene
(run-now (reset! stage (.. StageBuilder create
                           (title "Fracjure")
                           (scene (.. SceneBuilder create
                                      ;(height 480) (width 640)
                                      (root (.. VBoxBuilder create
                                                ;(minHeight 480) (minWidth 640)
                                                (children [(.. LabelBuilder create
                                                               (text "Hello World!")
                                                               build)])
                                                build))
                                      build))
                           build)))

;(run-now (.show @stage))


(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!")
  (run-now (.show @stage)))
```

Note that the above code works, the JavaFX window is displayed saying "Hello World!", "Hello, World!" is printed to the terminal, then the program exits.

Comment: I have discovered there are bugs in Mac OS/X Yosemite and JavaFX support.  In fact, it sometimes crashes my whole computer.  I filed a support request with Apple and they are aware of the problem.  This problem could be related to that bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line to

```
(run-now (.showAndWait @stage)))
```

Comment: Though this answer works, it doesn't seem to conform to JavaFX standards and I suspect it may cause problems somewhere else for complex applications.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, and perhaps more robust and standards conforming, is to provide an implementation of JavaFX's `Application` class.

You could include the Java code in your Leiningen project

```
package mypackage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Do nothing. This is just to get JavaFX started properly.
    }
    public static void initJavaFXApplication() {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

Then call from Clojure:

```
(MyApplication/initJavaFXApplication)
```

Leiningen supports having Java and Clojure sources by adding the following lines to your project.clj file:

```
:source-paths ["src/clojure"]
:java-source-paths ["src/java"]
```

And update your directory structure accordingly.